How to implement Snowflake streams in Snowflake native app
I am trying to implement a stream in Snowflake native app to the CDC on the consumer's table, which I got it with reference variable from manifest.yml file.
I am trying to create a stream as follows:
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM core.my_stream ON TABLE REFERENCE('table_reference'); 

I am able to create it successfully, but I am unable to get the data from my_stream in Snowflake native app, but I can access it directly from a consumer Snowflake account. I think it is a problem with roles and grants.
While accessing the streams through a Streamlit UI in native apps, it shows me the following error:

SnowparkSQLException: (1304): 01b704c3-020a-61eb-0007-eafb000652f2: 091901 (01000): Base table 'CUSTOMER_OPERATIONAL_DATA.PUBLIC.CHANGES' dropped, cannot read from stream 'MY_STREAM' in line 1 position 16.

What is the correct way of implementing streams in a Snowflake native app?
